# How to change document root to script’s public directory?

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, cpanel

I am setting up an admin panel on `cpanel`. I have bought this script from a company. I have completed all the steps mentioned in their documentation, but I am stuck on this step - `"change document root to script’s public directory: "`. Please help me solve this issue.

**EDIT**

Here is the link of documentation -
https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/fir-for-fiverr.appspot.com/o/Backend-Documentation.pdf?alt=media&token=d66f4200-e7e6-492a-b092-8e7e0ea97dd5

These files are in public folder - `.htaccess` -
https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/fir-for-fiverr.appspot.com/o/.htaccess?alt=media&token=b854ec7f-4d89-4f0c-b23f-337805f6bb31

`index.php` - https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/fir-for-fiverr.appspot.com/o/index.php?alt=media&token=fa1ef9bd-2676-478a-a8b2-3833430b3df1

Comment: You should give us more information, maybe some piece of code or a link to documentation and tell us what plugin or script you are trying to use.

Comment: Documentation link is added thanks

Comment: What about contacting support?

Comment: They are not replying from 27 days

Answer (score 0):

Try to change the existing path to the script (I guess it's defined somewhere in the script) the specific path in your webserver.

Code snippet might be useful.

Comment: better if this one is left in the comment instead

Comment: Commenting is disabled to me so far:/

Comment: Added please check

Comment: @Ahsin Mehmood - try to change the existing APP_URL(its set for localhost now) in .env to your own url

Comment: Its not an issue I have already set this url in cpanel I dont wants to share domain link

Comment: Ok, I thought that changing the default APP_URL value in .env file will solve the problem. If it's already changed that I have not better idea at the moment:/